# How to update values in List<Vector2> list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I just started to learn Windows Phone programming.

I have a list defined like this,

```
    private List<Vector2> _terrain;
    public List<Vector2> Terrain { get { return _terrain; } }
```

Under this, I fill the list with some vectors like this,

```
    level.Terrain.Add(new Vector2(i, (int)y));
```

lets say I got 50 elements in this list. What I want to do is, I want to remove the first item in this list, then move second item to first place, third to second etc., etc. What I want to do with this is I'm generating random "things". With this I'm planning to make them look like moving. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `List<T>` class tries to provide an abstraction to a structure that is a list of items.
So whenever an item is removed from the list, it's gone, and the list is compacted automagically. For example, if I had:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   numbers.Add(i+1); //adds the numbers 1 through 10
}

Console.WriteLine(numbers[0]); //writes out 1 - the first item
Console.WriteLine(numbers[3]); //writes out 4 - the fourth item
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count); //writes out 10 - there are ten elements

numbers.RemoveAt(0); //removes the first element of the list
Console.WriteLine(numbers[0]); //writes out 2 - the new first item
Console.WriteLine(numbers[3]); //writes out 5 - the new fourth item
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count); //writes out 9 - there are nine elements now

numbers.RemoveAt(3); //removes the fourth element of the list
Console.WriteLine(numbers[0]); //writes out 2 - still the first item
Console.WriteLine(numbers[3]); //writes out 6 - the new fourth item
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count); //writes out 8 - there are eight elements total
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want a Queue instead of a List.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
level.Terrain.RemoveAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generic Queue

```
Queue<Vector2> testQueue= new Queue<Vector2>();
```

[Also check this link for more information of generic Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)